# MySQL query: select all active in a table but accept an inactive which id = 1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know this one won't work but i give it a try, using union on the same table.

```
select  `sys_id`,`username`,`status`
    from  user_tbl
    WHERE  sys_id=1
UNION  ALL 
SELECT  `sys_id`,`username`,`status`
    from  user_tbl
    WHERE  status ='active'
    ORDER by  sys_id
```

another try

```
select  `sys_id`,`username`,`status`
    from  user_tbl
    WHERE  status='active' || sys_id=1
    ORDER by  sys_id
```

Is it possible?

all your selection is active but one item is inactive with an specified Id

```
1 | inactive
2 | active 
3 | active
4 | active
```

Comment: Incomplete specification.  Is `sys_id` unique?  Is it always `inactive`?  Do you care whether the inactive row comes first or last or in id order?  Etc.

Comment: And...  Do you want only one `inactive` entry, while getting all `active` ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `inactive` OR `(inactive with id 1)` can be achieved like this:

```
select `sys_id`,`username`,`status` from user_tbl WHERE status='active' or
(status='inactive' and sys_id=1) ORDER by sys_id
```

Comment: I mean all active and (one inactive with id=1

Answer (score 1):

just simple add and condition in your sys_id = 1

```
select  `sys_id`,`username`,`status`
    from  user_tbl
    WHERE  status='active' ||
          ( sys_id=1   and  `status`='inactive' )
    ORDER by  sys_id
```